# How to test API with POST requests to the database

Tags: javascript

I need to test an API with POST requests. Testing with supertest and chai. The problem is that the test is one-time, that is, it actually enters data into the database and the next time the test will not work, since the object has already been created, how can I get around this?

```
const request = require('supertest')('http://localhost:5000');
const assert = require('chai').assert;

it('POST /api/book/create', () => {
    const data = {
        "id" : "3",
        "title" : "Testt",
        "author" : "He",
        "vendorCode" : "1321",
        "year" : "10.10.2022",
        "numberOfCopies" : "100"
    };
    return request
        .post('/api/book/create')
        .send(data)
        .then((res) => {
            assert.equal(res.body.book.title, 'Testt');
            assert.equal(res.body.book.author, 'He')
        });
});
```

Comment: So you are submitting the same data over and over to the API and it won't allow you to resubmit since the data is the same? If that is the case, a simple solution is to pass a random number to the numeric fields. They will be different each time so the object would be different each time.

Comment: Well, in general, I would not want the data for testing to get into the database for work, is it possible to somehow clean it all up later?

Comment: There are a couple solutions. You have test tables only used for testing and switch to production for live. Or simply delete the records from the database.

Comment: I don't really understand how I should do it. I use sequelize